# 13.10 to 14.04 upgrade aborted but then completed

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, upgrade

I was upgrading from 13.10 t0 14.04 and the system said:

"Could not install the upgrades
The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a)."

After running this recovery it said the upgrade was complete but that there may be problems.

Any advice? (I am an ignorant man so PLEASE say it in very simple, step by step terms! :-) Thank you!